# Regex to match text containing a digit but not ending with a question mark

Tags: java, regex

I want to check whether a text contains a digit and is not a question, so I wrote the following Java code using a regular expression:

```
private static void containNumberNoQ(String commentstr){
     String urlPattern = "[^?]\\s\\d[^?]";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(commentstr);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
}
```

But when I try it with the following sentence, it matches, even though the sentence has a question mark:

```
just 2% of the result?
```

Why?

Comment: I have a requirement wherein I want to validate the text box with question(having textt and numbers) and having a question mark at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!.*?\\?).*\\d.*$
```

Try this.This will find sentences without `?` and with digits.

Comment: @HamedMinaee its a lookahead which make sure there is no `?` in the string anywhere

Comment: Sorry I will complete my question: Can u also explain this part: ^(?!.*?\\?)... for example what does this part do: ?!   or what is the role of ? aftre this part: .*   and when you say \\? are you refering to the real ? character or you mean quantifier?

Comment: @HamedMinaee ?! Is negative lookahead..... \\? Is real character not quantifier....

Comment: Thank u and also what is the role of ? aftre this part: .*

Comment: I have a requirement wherein I want to validate the text box with question(having textt and numbers) and having a question mark at the end of the sentence?

Comment: @forgottofly U can use `^[^?]*\\d[^?]*\\?$`

Answer (score 4):

Use the end of string anchor `$`. Also the `\\d` digit is not necessarily at the end of the question so you need to match possible characters between them

```
\\b\\d.*[^?]$
```

Comment: Thank u but when I try it with this sentence : "why I love u 2? testing the text"  it matches which should not

Comment: Alternatively, the problem could be solved without anchoring by using `Matcher.matches()` instead of `Matcher.find()` (still with some adjustments to the pattern, though).

Comment: The pattern given matches `"why I love u 2? testing the text"` because the question mark does not appear at the end.  If you want to avoid matching that text, then you need to be clearer about what you *do* want to match. What about `"I love u 2. Why?"`?  Or `"They say 2's company; is 3 a crowd?"`?.